How do I change (n.d.) using \autocite to german in overleaf
So I am currently writing my Bachelor's thesis. Everything works quite well but now I ran into a problem using Biblatex.
Here is an example:
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[style=apa, backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{references.bib}

\begin{document}

Hi this is a test \autocite[S. 12]{testquote}

\printbibliography[heading=bibintoc,title={Literaturverzeichnis}]

\end{document}

while my bib entry is the following:
@misc{testquote,
    title = {{test}},
    booktitle = {Quote},
    author = {{TestQuote}},
    url = {https://www.123abc.com}
}

so instead of my result showing "Hi this is a test (TestQuote, o. D., S. 12)" as it should in german, it shows "Hi this is a test (TestQuote, n.d., S. 12)" Same goes for the entry in the bibliography. How can I change this in order to have the correct language shown in here?
Thanks in advance.

(you could interpret n.d. as "nicht datiert" and the problem is solved :) )

You don't need to include the page prefix "S." in the postnote of cite commands. biblatex can add it automatically. Just say \autocite[12]{testquote} instead of S. 12.

oh that's so cool! Thanks @moewe

You could change the nodate string:
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[style=apa, backend=biber]{biblatex}

% just to generate an example bib file
\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{\jobname.bib}
@misc{testquote,
    title = {{test}},
    booktitle = {Quote},
    author = {{TestQuote}},
    url = {https://www.123abc.com}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\DefineBibliographyStrings{ngerman}{%
  nodate           = {Quack!},
}


\begin{document}

Hi this is a test \autocite[S. 12]{testquote}

\printbibliography[heading=bibintoc,title={Literaturverzeichnis}]

\end{document}



Thanks! reread your answer and it does work!
Any idea why "Quack!" generates the comma before "S. 12" but "o. D." will not have a comma after?

@Erd4 If you want "o.D." you need to say nodate = {{}o.\,D\adddot}, so that the . at the end is interpreted as an abbreviation dot and not a sentence-ending full stop/period. (The empty pair of braces in the beginning makes sure that "o.D." is never capitalised.)
